# How to make a Textbox Readonly, and have a calendar appear when clicked using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, readonly

I have 3 textbox's witch i would like to change to readonly. At the moment when you click on the textbox's a calendar appears where you can select a date. This is how i want it, but the user can also type in a date, i want this removed as it is a ipad app and then brings up the keyboard.

Could someone show me how to set my textbox's to readonly?

```
$('#AdvertiserSignDate').attr('readonly', true);
$('#ContinentalSignDate').attr('readonly', true);
$('#WitnessSignDate').attr('readonly', true);
```

If this is the wrong approach could you please give me a good redirection.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: it should be `$('#WitnessSignDate').attr('readonly', 'readonly);` but im not 100% sure

Comment: The code run's but the textbox's are not readonly.

Comment: Hey just to double check you want date picker text box to be read only with date picker enabled? I can make a demo for you! let me know if this is what you looking for

Comment: @Tats_innit Yes that is what i'm trying to achieve, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/h9bFb/5/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/6JAYJ/2/

Hope this helps;

**code**

```
  $(function () {

                $("#fromDate, #toDate").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1

                }).attr('readonly','true');

            });
​
```

**OR**

```
 $(function () {

                var dates = $("#fromDate, #toDate").datepicker({
                    defaultDate: "+1w",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    numberOfMonths: 1

                });

            });
```

**html**

```
<label for="from">From</label>
<input type="text" id="fromDate" name="fromDate" readonly='true'/>
<label for="to">to</label>
<input type="text" id="toDate" name="toDate" readonly='true'/>
```

Comment: No worries man @Pomster have a play around, don't forget to +1 and accept the answer B-)

Comment: +1 can have the accept when i'm done :p. Ok so im not using html but i have cshtml, how can i added the readonly='true' ........  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AdvertiserSignName, new { id = "txtAdvertiserSignName", @class = "mediumTextInput" })

Comment: try adding as it is like you added id attribute, let me know how it goes

Comment: @Pomster or do this http://jsfiddle.net/6JAYJ/2/ I am updating my answer checkout the second demo.

Comment: Thanks man, i'm sorted, it all works, just needed to change my html and add the read only, thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery UI calendar. Here you will get all the option to configure.
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#AdvertiserSignDate').keydown(function(event){
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Code run's fine no problems, but textbox is still not readonly, i can still type in ccharacters.

Comment: $('#AdvertiserSignDate').keydown(function(event){
$('#AdvertiserSignDate').val("");return false; 
});//check this one

Comment: Gave it ago, no effect, i can still type in values.

Comment: Hey but thats not possible right..can u debug the code? the code which i sent you means whver user will start tying the textbox the the textbox will be cleared..maybe in ur case keyboard will still be shown but even after typing the textbox should be empty in the end..you can try disabling the textbox but then calendar will not be shown u may need another button to show calendar beside textbox.